# Function to Convert UTC DateTime to GMT Time In Delphi XE5

Tags: delphi, utc, gmt

Please I Need a Function to Convert a UTC DateTime to GMT Format.
This Function Should Receive the UTC DateTime as a TDateTime and Return The GMT Time as a String.

Google Does Not Seem to Help Much.

Here is an Illustration

Current Value in UTC DateTime := 7/9/2014 11:36:51 PM

Needed Value in GMT Time := 2014-07-09 23:36:51

Delphi Version : XE5

Thanks.

Comment: I find Chris Rolliston's book titled 'Delphi XE2 Foundations' to be a priceless resource for questions like this.  Don't be thrown off by the 'XE2' in the title, it's relevant through XE6.

Comment: You mentioned the output needs to be a string. You can do the format conversion AND the type conversion at the same time using 'DateTimeToString'
   ---   Documentation:
http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE6/en/System.SysUtils.DateTimeToString

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`FormatDateTime`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.FormatDateTime) for this.

The [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.FormatDateTime) describes the format string options in detail. The format string that you need is:

```
yyyy-mm-dd hh:nn:ss
```